# Upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04 can't startx

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, 22.04, xorg

I just did the upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04, using do-release-upgrade

Everything went smoothly but now I am unable to start the graphical interface, I get an error message with a button to logout and I can see this error displaying after that :

`xf86EnableIO: failed to enable I/O ports 0000-03ff (Operation not permitted)`

I tried a lot from what I could find on Google, but so far it didn't work, if anyone could help ?

Comment: Have you been able to identify a specific device in relation to the error (by examining the /var/log/Xorg.N.log(s) for example)? Are you literally running `startx` or is the X server launched via a display manager? Can you [edit] your question to include a bullet-point summary of the things you tried?

Comment: So far I didn't see anything wrong in the Xorg log file, the only thing I see wrong is `(EE) Server terminated with error (2). Closing log file.` I'm going to update the post with what I've tried. And I use startx with the multi-user login so I have no graphical interface launched